# Second law of thermodynamics for finite changes

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, entropy

The internal energy energy of the system is $U=U(S,V)$ (without taking into account number of molecules for simplicity). The differential of this function is: $$dU=TdS-pdV$$ Then $$\int_{(S_1,V_1)}^{(S_2,V_2)}dU= \int_{(S_1,V_1)}^{(S_2,V_1)}TdS + \int_{(S_2,V_1)}^{(S_2,V_2)}-pdV$$
The temperature can be consider constant and taken out of the integral. Then:$$\Delta U=TΔS -pΔV$$

What if the temperature is not constant? The internal energy from Euler's theorem:is 
$$U=T(S,V)S-p(S,V)V$$ 
Therefore could $\Delta U$ be written as: 
 $$\Delta U = [T_2S_2-p_2V_2]-[T_1S_1-p_1V_1]$$

where in the case of constant temperature reduces to the above formula. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: Do you have a reference that says $T$ can be pulled out of the integral?

Comment: @jacob1729 I alright edited the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The equation U=TS-PV can't be correct because the definition of Gibbs free energy is G=U-TS+PV, and it is a state function (that changes).

Comment: @ChetMiller Indeed. There seems to be missing chemical potential $$U=TS-pV+\sum_i\mu_iN_i$$

Comment: I didn't include them for shake of simplicity. I would be grateful for an answer that includes chemical potential.